# SICStus Prolog upgrade in x86 platform

Tags: sicstus-prolog

Currently we are using SICStus  version :3.12.10 and patch1 (x86-linux-glibc2.3) for 32 bit platform.
My requirement: As per new requirement we have to upgrade SICStus Prolog Version 4.2.3 and x86 platform changed from 32 bit to 64 bit. could you please explain what are the code changes to be modified.

Edit: The predicates atom_codes/2, number_codes/2 are supported both Sicstus prolog version 3 and 4.similarly is there any Commonly accepted basic predicates in SICStus Prolog version 3.12.10 and SICStus Prolog version 4.2.3.could you please share if you have any reference document and link.

Edit: Is there any commonly accepted predicates in prolog version 3 and 4

Comment: Did you try `--iso` as recommended? It seems you are ignoring this advice.

Answer (score 2):

First, try to run your code in 3.12.10 with the `--iso` option. This covers many of the changes. I.e., there was a significant change from pre-ISO to ISO. With the help of switch `--iso` on and off  you should be able to get many of the differences.

The [release notes](http://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/relnotes.html/) might be helpful, too.

Then, consider that <s>to wait until 4.3 which is currently in beta</s> 4.3 has improved ISO conformity even further. Here is the [most recent documentation](http://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/).

Comment: could you please explain more on the above issue

Comment: @AyyappaBoligala: You need to tell what you do not understand.

Comment: The predicates atom_codes/2, number_codes/2 are supported both Sicstus prolog version 3 and 4.similarly is there any Commonly accepted basic predicates in SICStus Prolog version 3.12.10 and SICStus Prolog version 4.2.3.could you please share if you have any reference document and link.

Comment: I tried to compile --iso options.but it does not works for me.

Comment: @AyyappaBoligala: "it does not works for me" you need to make clear reproducible statements. Which version? Etc.

Comment: Hi false thank for reply.I will give clear statements .